# How I can access gmail at GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gmail

How I can access gmail at GAE? It seems that I can't use imap there. Is there any other way?

Comment: Actually I need read only access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for read access you can get to your gmail through an RSS feed, using [URLFetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html). The url is as such:

https://username:password@gmail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom